# how do I copy all folders & subfolder paths & file names to txt

Tags: copy

I have a folder named "unpacked" I am trying to copy all the folders and subfolder paths and file names to a txt file (check example below). How can I do this?

There are lots of files and subfolders I need to copy to txt, eg:

```
E:\unpacked\ABILITIES\CHARACTERS\ACROBAT.TXT
E:\unpacked\ABILITIES\CHARACTERS\AUDIOREACTIONS_AUTOGENERATED\BADCOPAUDIOREACTIONS.TXT
```

Answer (score 0):

`dir unpacked /s /b>unpacked.txt` writes to file `unpacked.txt`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).